# React Router redirect rendering a blank screen

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Currently having a small issue with ReactJS and the routing. I currently want my app to redirect back to the login screen if a token does not exist. The app should zero access to the other pages. If a user tries to input a url to redirect it without a valid token, it should default back to the login page.

My code is as follows at present.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
        ...

  render() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        {!token ? <Route render={() => <Redirect push to="/" />} /> :
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/validate" component={ValidateLoginContainer} />
          <Route exact path="/home" component={Landing} />
          <Route exact path="/non-arrivals" component={NonArrivals} />
          <Route exact path="/due-in-summary" component={DueInSummary} />
          <Route exact path="/due-in-forecast" component={DueInForecastDetail} />
          <Route exact path="/hourly-arrivals-departures" component={HourlyArrivalsDepartures} />
          <Route exact path="/overstays" component={Overstays} />
        </Switch>
      }
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
```

Trouble is it redirects fine, but renders a blank screen.

Update code, still same error:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route render={() => {
            if (!token) {
              return <Redirect push to="/" />;
            }
               return <Redirect push to="/home" />;
           }}
      />

      <Redirect exact from="/" to="/home" />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/validate" component={ValidateLoginContainer} />
      <Route exact path="/home" component={Landing} />
      <Route exact path="/non-arrivals" component={NonArrivals} />
      <Route exact path="/due-in-summary" component={DueInSummary} />
      <Route exact path="/due-in-forecast" component={DueInForecastDetail} />
      <Route exact path="/hourly-arrivals-departures" component={HourlyArrivalsDepartures} />
      <Route exact path="/overstays" component={Overstays} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: @MilosMosovsky nope, just a warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you are now inside a infinite loop as when users tries to navigate without a token you are redirecting to `/` but with your ternary rendering you are rendering only

`<Route render={() => <Redirect push to="/" />} />` so the component for `Login` is not defined, you would need to either change ternary operator to also render `Login` always (basically now you are returning only redirect always when you don't have a token, that's why you have blank page, you need to add also route for login in ternary switch, it should be inside the `true` branch not `false` branch), or change implementation like:

***authenticatedPage.js***

```
export function authenticatedPage (Component) {
  const componentName = Component.displayName || Component.name || 'Component'

  return class extends React.Component {
    static displayName = `Route(${componentName})`

    renderPage () {
      return (
        <Component {...this.props} />
      )
    }

    render () {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
      if (token) {
        return this.renderPage()
      } else {
        return <Redirect to='/login' />
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import { authenticatedPage } from './authenticatedPage.js'

      <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                  {/* Authentication Routes */}
                  <Redirect exact from='/' to='/home' />
                  <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />

                  {/* Authenticated Routes */}
                  <Route exact path='/home' component={authenticatedPage(Landing)} />/> */}
                </Switch>
     </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: this triggers A <Router> may have only one child element

Comment: Milos, see updated code, still triggering same issue with a blank screen :(

Comment: @MubeenHussain I've updated the answer to a implementation how it should look like, and how it should be done in a proper way, HoC wrapping, I tested it locally